# Adding 301 redirect to a php file

Tags: php

Can you help me with this one :

I have that link : http://www.zyz.com/www_night/index.php

I'would like redirect my site to www.zyz.com, with PHP, when in url appears "www_night"

i try to do it something like that :

```
if(isset($_GET['www_night'])) {
header("Location: http://www.zyz.com/", true, 301);
}
```

Comment: That is done with .htaccess config, you will find plenty of info on here to do that

Answer (score 2):

Do a condition:

```
if (preg_match("/www_night/i", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.zyz.com/");
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header('Location: http://www.zyz.com/');
```